# Date and Time Format

Tags: java, android, time, formatting

Greeting!

I've done a project that can send GPS Coordinates to mobile number Automatically, The Recipients received like this example format "**lat:14.7836139 long:12.71104 speed:0.0 Date:1309325189000**"
and now I want a format for a date and time like this **Date:dd/mm/yy hh:mm** Anyone who can Help me?

here is my sample code I use.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

{

loc.getLatitude();

loc.getLongitude();
String Text = "lat:" + loc.getLatitude() + " "
+ "long:" + loc.getLongitude()+" "
+ "speed:" + loc.getSpeed() +" " 
+ "date:" + loc.getTime();   

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

Text,

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();


if (phoneNo.length()>0 && Text.length()>0)                
    sendSMS(phoneNo, Text);               


}
```

Comment: You should never hardcode that date format.  Either hardcode the international standard format yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM (or a computer-readable form of it like 2011-06-29T14:26:54Z) or use a user-selected / locale based format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleDateFormat should do the trick, you can then set the format mask yourself. Alternatively you could use the android Time class, but that is a bit more tricky mask wise.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
dateTimeFormat.format(new Date(loc.getTime()));
```

Comment: You probably mean `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"`, had to debug this in one of my apps for a LONG time... Besides, the orig. question specified the format as `"dd/MM/yy hh:mm"`...

Answer (score 1):

Being a development question, this should be moved to StackOverflow, but here's a tip:
`DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT).format(loc.getTime()));`

See the official documentation on the relevant classes [around here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) to tweak it to suit your needs.

Comment: I tried this..    "Date:" + android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yy hh:mm", new java.util.Date());;