# Android : date format in a String

Tags: java, android, string, date, format

I have a problem to sort date because of the format of these dates.

I obtain the date :

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

And I build a String with these values.

```
dateRappDB = (new StringBuilder()
   .append(mYear).append(".")
   .append(mMonth + 1).append(".")
   .append(mDay).append(" ")).toString();
```

The problem is that if the month is for example February, mMonth value is 2. So dates with months like October (10) comes before in my list.

What I need is that month and day are formated like MM and dd. But I don't know how to do it in my case.

**EDIT** :

**I solved the problem by using a DateFormat like said above.**

I replaced this :

```
dateRappDB = (new StringBuilder()
  .append(mYear).append(".")
  .append(mMonth + 1).append(".")
  .append(mDay).append(" ")).toString();
```

By this :

```
Date date = new Date(mYear - 1900, mMonth, mDay);
dateFacDB = DateFormat.format("yyyy.MM.dd", date).toString();
```

And it works. 
Thanks to all of you for your help :)

Comment: try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165901/android-date-and-time-format

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705031/how-to-format-a-date

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520553/date-and-time-format

Answer (score 38):

here is a simple way to convert Date to String :

`SimpleDateFormat simpleDate =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");`

`String strDt = simpleDate.format(dt);`

Answer (score 22):

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 Date now = calendar.getTime();   
 String timestamp = simpleDateFormat.format(now);
```

These might come in handy

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
   new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZZZZ");
```

this format is equal to --> "2016-01-01T09:30:00.000000+01:00"

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
   new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ");
```

this format is equal to --> "2016-06-01T09:30:00+01:00"

Answer (score 8):

here is the example for date format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = new Date();

System.out.println("format 1 " + sdf.format(date));

sdf.applyPattern("E MMM dd yyyy");
System.out.println("format 2 " + sdf.format(date));
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to sort dates, not strings. Also, have you heared about [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html)? It makes all that appends for you.

Comment: I second this solution, unless for some unsaid reason you really need to work with those strings... but ernazm hits the nail on the head: use the Android classes :D

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue, you create a list of dates and since they're strings, they get arranged in a dictionary-order number-wise, which means you get october before february (10 before 2).

If I were you, I would store my results in a container where I control the insertion point (like an array list) or where I can control the sorting algorithm.